# Java rewrite function compact and readable which allows you to extract code from long enough text

Tags: java, android, string, split

I have the following sample text like:

`I sent you the link, very long test...... here: https://example.com/d/codeToTake`

I have to make sure that I get the final code, which would be `codeToTake`.

I have the following function but I would like it to be more compact and readable:

```java
public static String extractLinks(String text) {
        List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher m = Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(text);
        while (m.find()) {
            String url = m.group();
            links.add(url);
        }

        return links.toArray(new String[links.size()])[0].split("/")[4];
}
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: Something like `List<String> urlEnds = links.stream().map(link ->link.replaceAll(".*/([^/ ]+)", "$1")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: It doesn't work, it only returns the last letter of the code.

Comment: Then there must be something strange in your `List`. If I add *either* the whole of your sample text *or* the url in it to a `List` I get the output: `[codeToTake]` in my terminal

Comment: I'm trying it on android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the last of the string always comes after a /.

```
public static String extractLinks(String text) {
        int index  = text.lastIndexOf("/");
        String subString = text.substring(index+1);
        System.out.println(subString);
        return subString;
}
```